# Convergence of $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} |X_i - \hat{\mu}|$, where $\hat{\mu}$ is the sample median.

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to show the following. i.e. the convergence of sample mean absolute deviation.

Let $X_1, \ldots X_n$ be **order** statistics from $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$.

$\hat{\xi} \equiv \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} |X_i - \hat{\mu}|$, where $\hat{\mu} = X_{n/2}$ (**sample median**).

I would like to show that $\hat{\xi}$ can be expressed in another form, that is,

$\hat{\xi} \equiv \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} |X_i - \mu| + R(\mu, \hat{\mu})$

where $R(\mu, \hat{\mu}) \underset{n \to \infty}{\to} 0$

---

What I **tried**:

Let $r_n$ such that $X_{r_n} < \hat{\mu} < X_{r_{n+1}}$, and $s_n$ such that $X_{s_n} < \mu < X_{s_{n+1}}$.

I'm trying to simplify the formula, but I keep failing.

Is there anyone to help me out?

Comment: What do you mean by **ordered** random variables?

Comment: @uniquesolution I assume what the OP means is that $X_1, \dots, X_n$ refer to the order statistics: i.e., $X_1 \leq X_2 \leq \cdots \leq X_n$, with $X_1 = \min_{i}X_i$ and $X_n = \max_{i}X_i$.

Comment: Oh, I edited the term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is actually much simpler than it seems.

First, note that for any real numbers $a,b,c$, we have $$\Big| |a - b| - |a - c| \Big| \leq |b - c|\,.$$

To prove this, just break it down case-by-case.

This implies that $|R(\mu,\hat{\mu})| \leq |\mu - \hat{\mu}|$.  The result then follows from the fact that $\hat{\mu} \to \mu$ as $n \to \infty$.